# Get TOKEN auth2 - POST client data - bad request

Tags: reactjs, api, symfony, fosrestbundle

I hava a problem (404 : Bad request ) when consuming token API in my react APP .
In Post man, it work very well

```
  const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: "no-cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
            cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
            credentials: "include", // include, *same-origin, omit
            redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
            referrer: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
            headers: {
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "client_id": "1_15dpzlnknhtwk8sgo4gwo800okogc4g00gk4k04g4g0cgc0ww0",
                "client_secret": "dc86f30rr6okw8w84c8owkcko08s4k8k4c4c4k04osow8skko",
                "grant_type": "password",
                "username": "demoUsername",
                "password": "demoPassword"
            })
        };
```

---

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/oauth/v2/token', requestOptions)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log('response');
        console.log(response);

    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
    });
```

the result is  :

[image]

[image]

this is my security.yml

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the symfony project where the api is built? If the awnser is yes, execute php bin/console debug:route and check "oauth/v2/token" appear in the list

Comment: Yes, in my localhost - I can test it with postMan and work very well

Comment: fos_oauth_server_token              GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /oauth/v2/token

Comment: Have you tried to send the body as an object instead of a string?

Comment: yes,always - 404 bad - request

Comment: If you paste "http://localhost:8000/oauth/v2/token" in your browser, is it still returning a 404?

Comment: paste your security.yml too please

Comment: in browser : {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}

Comment: security.yml pasted in edit

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of header.the header is empty
It's work now